# How do you secure information between 2 servers?

Tags: node.js

Forgive me I'm still very new to this.

I am building multiple front ends which all need to be able to speak to a single back end server api. These front ends are hosted on different domains so I ran into CORS issues and from what I've gathered my best solution is to send the appropriate data on the front end to a proxy server on the same domain which then forwards that request to my api server.

I'm concerned about the security of this action though and looking for the right way to secure the data being passed from the proxy server to the api server.

So my data goes:

**client --> proxy --> api**

and I want to know the best way to make sure the api knows the proxy is who it claims to be. Is my best bet just a simple password exchange? A json web token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JWT actually. The proxy server can send a JWT along with each request to the API server, and the API server can then validate the token to ensure that it was issued by a trusted source.

Here's a scenario how JWT authentication might work in this:

1. The client makes a request to the proxy server, including any data
   that needs to be sent to the API server.
2. The proxy server generates a JWT, which includes a unique identifier
   for the client and any other relevant information, and signs it with
   a secret key.
3. The proxy server sends the request, along with the JWT, to the API
   server.
4. The API server receives the request and extracts the JWT from the
   header.
5. The API server validates the JWT by checking the signature against
   the secret key and verifying that the JWT has not been tampered
   with.
6. If the JWT is valid, the API server extracts the client identifier
   and uses it to determine whether the request should be processed.
7. If the JWT is not valid, the API server returns an error response to
   the proxy server.

Note:

It's important to keep the secret key used for signing the JWT secure, as it is the key to ensuring the authenticity of the JWT. It's also a good idea to regularly update the secret key to further enhance security.